# Installing issues in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

I get `python-setuptools is already the newest version.

Now when I run 
`import networkx`

I get `ImportError: No module named networkx`

Please help.

Comment: you need to install `networkx` it is not in the standard library https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/install.html

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use `pip`. It allows you to install Python packages from their names. Here is an example.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install networkx
```

Then `networkx` is installed :

```
$ python
>>> import networkx
>>>
```